# How do I get a text input from a dynamically selected text input box in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a multiple TextInput named `input_x` where x is a number (e.g input_1, input_2 etc.,). I also have multiple buttons named `btn_x` where x is a number (e.g btn_1, btn_2 etc.,).

When a `btn_x` is pressed, I should be able to print the value of the input that has matches the x value (e.g when btn_2 is pressed, value inside input_2 will be printed.)

This is my current attempt that does not work:

```
fun handleClickButton (view: View) {
    with (view as Button) {
        var this_btn = view.resources.getResourceEntryName(id)
        val id_string = this_btn
        val delim = "_"
        val arr = id_string.split(delim).toTypedArray()
        val id_num = arr[2]
        val this_input = "input_" + arr[2].toString()
        print(binding.this_input.text)
    }
}
```

Any help would be really really appreciated! I am very new to android development and Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the issues that need to fix:

- Getting `arr[2]` while the length of the `arr` is 2; So this should be `arr[1]` as arrays are 0-baed indices to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
- A text value is invoked on the `binding` object with this expression `binding.this_input` and `binding` requires to have a view id:

Not sure if you can use view bindings for an int as view ID, because this reference name of that view is not registered in the generated binding class.

But at least you can achieve that with `findViewById`:

Applying that in your code:

```
fun handleClickButton(view: View) {
    with(view as Button) {
        val this_btn = view.resources.getResourceEntryName(id)
        val id_string = this_btn
        val delim = "_"
        val arr = id_string.split(delim).toTypedArray()
        val id_num = arr[1]
        val this_input = "input_" + arr[1]
        val id = resources.getIdentifier(this_input, "id", context.packageName)
        val input = this@MainActivity.findViewById<EditText>(id)
        print(input.text)
    }
}
```

Note: I'm assuming the surrounding activity as `MainActivity`, you can replace it with your activity as omitting it will get `findViewById()` called on the button.